# How can I keep the search box absolute in the top navigation (& keep is smoothly responsive!)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm a novice programmer and i've had a couple more experienced programmers try to work this out but no real luck.

I'm needing to add the search box to the top navigation and that the search box could be responsive at various screen sizes - [Link to sample mockups here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s319/sh/f5fe469d-7704-46fe-b654-02881677e489/2ef87ff6bde06b5087576b635550cb53)

The search bar [is currently wrapping/displacing here.](http://budgetconferencing.martechlab.com/)

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

Set the search bar itself (the div) to display: inline-block`.  That will get it to position properly.

div.header-phoneicon: right: 350px

Then, move the phone number back to give it space.  Change the `div.header-phoneinfo` css `right` property to fit it in.

You need to adjust the `width` and `right` properties to fit everything in.

Answer (score 0):

That will require a few media query in order to float when the screen is wide enough - "mobile first".

```
.search {
     float: none;
}

@media (min-width: [tablet_width] ) {
  .search, 
  .phone {
     float: left;
  }
}
```